# Gerund for repetitive, intermittent, from time-to-time actions?

Tags: gerunds, present-tense

Sentence:

1) She is **crying** at night (every night) - *present simple*

2) He is **flying** on Fridays (every Friday) - *present simple*

3) They are *fishing* every weekend - *present simple*

As far as I know, for some kind of repetitive, intermittent, from time-to-time actions, I shouldn't use a gerund. It feels right for me to use gerund but I have to confirm this usage by exact rule

Question:

> Is there exact rule for usage of a gerund in present simple cases?

Comment: "She is crying at night" is not present simple! It's present continuous or present progressive.

Comment: None of your examples are gerunds. As @Cardinal notes, they are all _progressive_ or _continuous_ usages, and the "-ing" words are _participles._ The gerund is the noun form of a verb, e.g.: _**Fishing** is my favorite hobby._

Comment: I took the liberty of retitling your question to narrow it to just the kinds of actions you're asking about. Please double-check to make sure you agree with the new title.

Comment: I understand what you mean. _She cries at night_ and _He flies on Fridays_ might be better for more permanent activities like those in 1) and 2), though 3) seems more natural as you've written it.

Comment: @BillJ Isn't _They fish every weekend_ yet more natural?

Comment: I don't think _They fish every weekend_ is very natural. More likely is _They go fishing every weekend_, or perhaps  _They are fishing every weekend_.

Comment: @BillJ Good catch! (So to speak.) I just updated my answer with a note about "fish" vs. "go fishing".

Answer (score 4):

First, let's get rid of some mythology.
English only has two tenses: **Past** and **Non-Past** (aka **Present**).

It also has a **Progressive** construction, which consists of an auxiliary verb *be*, followed by the present active participle form of the verb (i.e, the *-ing* form, which is not the same as a gerund). Progressive active verb constructions can refer either to individual events, like the first sentence below, or to a series of events (the "generic" reading), like the second sentence below.

- *Bill is sleeping downstairs tonight.*  (individual event)
- *Bill is sleeping downstairs these days.*  (generic reading)

But the simple present (non-past) with no progressive has the same options.

- *Bill sleeps downstairs tonight.*  (individual event)
- *Bill sleeps downstairs these days.* (generic reading)

Furthermore, the past tense also has the same property

- *Bill slept downstairs last night.*  (individual event)
- *Bill slept downstairs for three months.* (generic reading)

So this has nothing to do with gerunds, or tenses, or even progressives.
This has to do with [English generic sentences](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html), which are, admittedly, pretty complex.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact rule. Different tenses just make different suggestions about the time frame or emphasize different things about the time.

The examples you gave are all in the **present continuous tense**. This tense means that something is ongoing right now. Its most basic meaning is that something started in the (usually recent) past, has continued through the present, and is still happening. Some people call this "progressive" because the action is "in progress", but I like "continuous" because it's just like continuity in mathematics: the time interval when the verb applies has no breaks.

The present continuous tense suggests that the action or state is *temporary.* A listener understands it as suggesting that the action or state is tightly bound to time, specifically to right now.

The alternative you're looking for is the **simple present tense**. The simple present suggests that the activity or state is not tightly bound to time. It's used for eternal or timeless facts, like "Two plus two **equals** four." It's also used for relatively permanent facts, like "Bill Johnson **works** at Burger King."

If you say "Bill Johnson **is working** at Burger King", this suggests that it's a temporary job. You would likely say this if he's looking for other work, or maybe if conversation has established that Burger King is going out of business.

So, here are some contexts to illustrate typical ways you'd use each form of the verb, for each of your example sentences. You *could* swap with the other tense in each case, but the sentences below make the more natural choice, the one that "agrees" best with the time frame being described:

> Her boyfriend just dumped her. Last week, he sent her a text message saying "We're through" and hasn't contacted her since. She**'s crying** every night, but I think she'll be over him in another few days.
>
> Her husband died in 2010. She has never gotten over him. She **gets out** his picture and his love poetry and she **cries** every night.

---

> John **is doing** emergency work at the oil rig in Alaska. He **is flying** out there every Monday morning and **flying** home on Fridays until the rig is repaired.
>
> Robert **works** as a pilot for Southwest Airlines. He **flies** on Fridays from New York to Phoenix.

---

> Don took Rick on his first fishing trip in March. Now Rick can't get enough of it. He just spent $600 on fishing tackle. At first they **were going** to Lake Pymatuning once a month, but **now** they**'re fishing** every weekend.
>
> Chris and Terry have established a ritual that helps them unwind after the stress and chaos of each week at the fireworks factory. They **go** fishing every weekend at Lake Pymatuning.

Notice the past continuous **were going**. The monthly trips happened "at first" (suggesting a temporary, relatively short time frame), and they're not happening anymore. And who knows how long the present frequency will last?

By the way, usually when people talk about casual, amateur fishing trips, they say that you "go fishing", not that you "fish". Usually "fish" as a verb without "go" refers to professional fishing: "They **fish** until December and then they take a vacation until the Spring thaw." When there's a direct object specifying the type of fish, though, people drop the "go" and say "They **fish crappie** during the summer" even when amateurs do it. As usual, though, none of this is a rule.